# How to get the right xpath with the same name? Scrapy

Tags: xpath, scrapy

It's my first question. I'm trying to get the data, throught scrapy, of a webpage.

```
<dl class="pairing">
     <dt class="attribute" title="Maridaje">Maridaje:</dt>
     <dd>
</dl>
<dl>
<dl>
     <dt class="attribute" title="Vol. de alcohol">Vol. De Alcohol:</dt>
     <dd>14%</dd>
</dl>
```

As you can see, there are some instances using the same class name. I only want to get the text in one. How can I specify which one am I referring?

I have tried

```
item['maridaje'] = response.xpath('.//*[@class="attribute"]/text()').extract()
```

But this only give me all the titles of the clases with the same name.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple options:

- by index in XPath (1 based): `.//*[@class="attribute"][1]/text()`
- use `extract_first()` if the desired one is the first element:

  ```
  response.xpath('.//*[@class="attribute"]/text()').extract_first()
  ```
- by index in Python (0 based), getting the second match:

  ```
  response.xpath('.//*[@class="attribute"]/text()').extract()[1]
  ```
- check the parent: `.//dl[@class="pairing"]/dt[@class="attribute"]/text()`
- check the `title` attribute: `.//*[@class="attribute" and @title="Maridaje"]/text()`

Comment: thank you really much! .//*[@class="attribute" and @title="Maridaje"]/text() was what i was looking for